# How to group by(mysql) a particular timestamp range to show data in graphs?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to use a table data that I have to use in graphs in a format shown in picture below.
[Demo graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9est.png)

This is my data table below
[sql data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SxgC.png)

My goal is to use filters on that, in which timestamp range will be same as shown in graphs, and I have to filter it based on system.

For example, on 28 January 2022, system "3IN1" got down 3 three, and on 29th January ,it got down 0 time and so on till a week. Then similarly for all the systems mentioned in image below. How to achieve it with a sql query and group by.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... assuming start_timestamp is actually a TIMESTAMP data type

```sql
SELECT
  system_name,
  TO_CHAR(start_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date,
  SUM(current_status) as current_status,
  SUM(downtime) AS downtime
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  system_name, TO_CHAR(start_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```